# Resistance changes when keeping two ends of a metal bar constant but increasing the thickness of the middle?

Tags: resistors, resistivity

In this imaginary scenario I am taking a metal block and measuring the resistance. If I were to add a piece of metal in the middle of the metal block (i.e. the metal now has a bulging middle but the two ends of the block are still the same dimensions), would this change the resistance?
From the resistivity equation, I don't think it will but I was wondering if anybody could verify this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Think about it as three resistors in series - thin one, then thick, then another thin. So if you change the diameter (read - cross-section area) of the middle one, will its resistance change? Will the overall resistance change?

Comment: What resistivity equation are you using? Hit the [edit] link ...

Comment: Of course it would change the resistance.   It would be lower.  All one has to do is look at resistance charts of AWG wires.   As they get thicker, the bulk resistance drops.    Heck, if you can identify this mystery metal, and you can identify the dimensions, calculating the effect would be relatively simple.

Comment: You can consider it as three resistors in series. Do you know the equation for how to combine series resistances to get the equivalent resistance?

Comment: So if edges of middle are widely separated from edges, the decrease in resistance would not be proportional to the full cross sectional area, but it mould be significant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this question is not quite as simple as suggested in the comments above.

All materials have a bulk resistivity measured in ohm-meters. From [Wikipedia, we have:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity)

> Electrical resistivity (also called specific electrical resistance or
> **volume resistivity**) and its inverse, electrical conductivity, is a
> fundamental property of a material that quantifies how strongly it
> resists or conducts electric current. A low resistivity indicates a
> material that readily allows electric current. Resistivity is commonly
> represented by the Greek letter ρ (rho). **The SI unit of electrical
> resistivity is the ohm-meter (Ω⋅m)**.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4aIJ.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bitm2.png) For example, if a 1 m × 1
> m × 1 m solid cube of material has sheet contacts on two opposite
> faces, and the resistance between these contacts is 1 Ω, then the
> resistivity of the material is 1 Ω⋅m.

For example, copper has a volume resistivity of 1.68 × 10<sup>−8</sup> Ω⋅m at 20 °C.

Note the units. If you divide volume resistivity (Ω⋅m) by cross sectional area of a conductor (m²) you get Ω/m which is the **resistivity of that conductor per meter**.

Which is to say - if you increase the cross sectional area of the middle part of your conductor, you will decrease the resistance by some amount.
[image]

However this isn't the entire story.

For example, what is the resistance of the below conductor?

[image]

Another way of asking this is - **when I apply a voltage across the ends of this conductor, where does the current flow?**

The answer is that the current is not equally distributed across changes of cross sectional area (or, for that matter, at sharp bends in a conductor.) This is the "stream line" effect as discussed in the Copper Development Association publication [*Copper for Busbars*](https://copperalliance.org.uk/knowledge-base/resource-library/busbars-guidance-design-installation/), section 6.3.1 *Jointing of Copper Busbars - Joint resistance - Streamline effect*.

[image]

[image]

As with all decent engineering questions - the answer is ultimately "it depends."